# MongoDB Compass Reference

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, mongodb-compass

I was trying to use mongodb compass to create a sample database where I can insert documents to collection but is it possible to refer (database reference) other documents? I couldnt find any info regarding this.

Comment: what would you like to do

Comment: Let's say we have two collections called user and task. User collection would document the usual fields like username, password, etc... And in the task collection, we would have the date of post, content, etc... But the problem that I am having is how to refer userid in task collection without embedding. I can do it on nodejs but not on MongoDB compass

Answer (score 0):

I think it is, since you have ways of "connecting" documents to each other. Not such as relations inside RDBMS but by referring to the the other document id or embedding it.

You can simplily write the field "userId" or "user" or whatever you like and fulfill it with with the id of the user as a string.

Interesting [article](https://dev.to/damcosset/mongodb-normalization-vs-denormalization) about it.